Is this an auto part?
My son sent me this picture:
It looks vaguely like an engine thermostat, but the proportions are wrong.  An image search found dozens of hits, but all of them are sites touting "alien abductions."

Where did your son get it, was he asking you about it in relation to automotive repair?

It was an illustration in a (probably fake) newspaper article claiming it was found in someone's spinal column.  I was trying to find what it really is to show him that it is NOT evidence of alien abduction. :-)
